# How could users import pictures on website

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a blog and I want users to be able to upload pictures. How can I do this. My blog is made in HTML with python, Jinja2 and google app engine.

Thank you, 
Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the blobstore and reference between user model and image model, for example:

```
class Image(db.Model): 
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(User,
                                     collection_name='matched_images', verbose_name='Title')
    primary_image = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

... more fields if you like. And then handling your file / image upload over HTTP post:

```
class Upload(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):    
    def post(self):

        #... do form upload stuff and then get all uploaded images
        for upload in self.get_uploads():
            try:
                img = Image(reference=user)
                img.primary_image = upload.key()
                img.put()
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

For upload you can use the blobstore: See the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob

Images from the blobstore can be served by Google, using: get_serving_url:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blobstore. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob

Good luck.